# 1.9 CE - Set variable to either region or region_id if customer in USA

Tags: magento-1.9, billing, state, directory

Appologies but new to PHP...

Need to pass a value for 'state' to payment gateway which can be any string for non USA customers but must be two character code for USA (based on drop down list).

```
'State'=> $billingaddress->getData('region'),

'State'=> $billingaddress->getData('region_id'),
```

are the two variable.

Not sure of the if else syntax for setting 'state' as 'region_id' if country is USA and 'region' for all other countries.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, notice that I added a call to isRegionTwoCharFormat() which you would have to implement, so the sintax could be like this:

```
if(isRegionTwoCharFormat($billingaddress->getData('region'))) {
    $state = 'US';
} else {
    $state = 'SomethingElse';
}
```

Or you can also use ternary operator:

```
$state = isRegionTwoCharFormat($billingaddress->getData('region')) ? 'US' : 'SomethingElse';
```